# php not clearing table between different queries

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using jquery to feed variables to a php page.

I want the php to clear a table in the database, load new data based on the variables, query the new data and echo out results.

The problem is, the php doesn't seem to be clearing the table each time I hit the php page. When I feed two sets of variables to the php page, the same results appear for both queries. The results are a combination of what I want. What am I doing wrong, anyone know?

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/getTotals.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {year : strYear, race: 'USP', type: strType},
    success: function(data) {
        var objPrez = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        fillTotal(objPrez, tbl_prezresults);

    },
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        console.log(statusText + " " + err);
    }
});

//get gov totals
$.ajax({
    url: "php/getTotals.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {year : 2010, race: 'GOV', type: strType},
    success: function(data) {
        var objGov = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        fillTotal(objGov, tbl_govresults);

    },
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        console.log(statusText + " " + err);
    }
});
```

getTotals.php:

```
require_once ('constants_test.php'); 

$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
}
if( $_POST) {
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['type']);
    $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['year']);
    $race = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['race']);

    $db->query("delete from elections_temp");

    $data = array();
    $q = "INSERT INTO elections_temp (SELECT * FROM elections where electionOffice = '" . $race . "' AND electionYear = '" . $year . "' AND electionType = '" . $type . "')";
    $db->query($q); 
    $q_sums = "select firstName, lastName, party, sum(votes) as totvotes from elections_temp group by lastName order by totvotes desc";
    $result = $db->query($q_sums);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //Add this row to the reply
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

    $db->close();

} else {
    echo "You shouldn't be here.";
}
```

Comment: `$db->query("delete from elections_temp");` is not valid, looks like you want [truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)

Comment: `delete from some_table` is valid SQL, at least insofar as it works fine in the MySQL console.  Does it really break when using mysqli?

Comment: The delete should work. I wonder why you create a tmp-table and not use the select from the original table.

Comment: My question would be, why the temp table?  You could combine the two queries: `SELECT firstName, lastName, party, sum(votes) totvotes FROM elections WHERE electionOffice = ? AND electionYear = ? AND electionType = ? GROUP BY lastName, firstName, party ORDER BY totvotes DESC` and get the same results.

Comment: Did u put constraints on the table?

Comment: I needed to get a sum on a query result and having a temp table was the way I settled on achieving that goal.

Comment: Can you echo out your insert statement ($q) and confirm, that the post-variables are correct?

Comment: @DarkBee: what do you mean by contraints? In phpMyadmin I created a new mysql table with the same data structure as my original table.

Comment: Did u add foreign keys? But i'm thinking its irrelevant as u said it works in the mysql console. Are u using the same mysql credentials as the console ones?

Comment: @LauraNMS: "Constraints" being primary keys, foreign keys and such.  If anything's referring to `elections_temp` via a foreign key, that could keep the rows from getting deleted.  But yeah, if it works fine in myadmin, it's more likely a permissions issue with the user you're connecting as.

Comment: @Seb: POST variables are correct.

Comment: @DarkBee: Yes, same mysql credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need the extra table. You can all do it in one sql

```
$query = 'select firstName, lastName, party, sum(votes) as totvotes from elections 
where electionOffice = "' . $race . '" AND electionYear = ' . $year . ' AND electionType = "' . $type . '"
group by lastName, firstName, party order by totvotes desc';
```

If performance is a problem, add an index to electionOffice, electionYear and electionType (all in one index).

Comment: You're correct - tho I didn't think that would matter. $query should be "SELECT firstName, lastName, party, sum(votes) as totvotes FROM elections where electionOffice = '" . $race . "' AND electionYear = '" . $year . "' AND electionType = '" . $type . "' group by lastName, firstName order by totvotes desc"

Comment: I'd upvote just for recommending getting rid of `elections_temp`, but the other answer actually explains the problem caused by its existence, which really needs to be emphasized IMO.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is the following:

2 ajax calls that call the php script at the same time (probably a delay of a few ms between them).

The server then does what you want it to do, but strange things happen because of your temp table that is created/truncated every request.

What happens is the following:

1. request1 enters
2. runs the php code
3. request2 enters
4. runs request2 code
5. request1run locks tem table in database and starts creating it and stuff
6. request2run wants to create the same temp tabel but can't because request1run is still doing stuff
7. request1run ends doing his stuff in the db temp table
8. request2run now does his thing with the temp table, delete all records and add stuff
9. request1run has to wait before he can select stuff from the temp table because request2run is still doing his business.
10. request2run finished creating the temp table and request1run can slect his data and return it to the client
11. request2run select data and returns it to the client

So, because you fire both ajax call at the same timen they end up messing with each other on the server.

Your server is probably not fast enough to handle request1 before request2 kicks in.

Comment: Reason #13 why a (not-so-)temporary table is a bad idea.  :)  Good catch.  One could possibly use a real temporary table (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE elections_temp AS SELECT....`), but there's really no good reason that i can see here for a temp table in the first place.

Comment: @Pinoniq - thank you! This explains why those weird things were happening.